# How do I pass the password to a net use command which contains % at the end?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have this command in batch script

`net use \\192.168.40.40  /user:192.168.40.40\Administrator b91A*9AIvPr%`

But when it runs I get the error
System error 1326 has occurred.

The user name or password is incorrect.

Because it strips off last % symbol
Putting password in "" doesn't help either.

I cannot change password for the account. So are there any workaround?

Comment: I hope that's an example password and not the real one. If it's the real one, and you can't change it, you're probably going to be in a bit of trouble...

Comment: at first this is modified password not real, second that IP is local IP not public so even the password was real it is not useful

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few solutions to your problem

1. Use a variable for the `password`

```
    set "password=b91A*9AIvPr%"
    net use \\192.168.40.40 /user:192.168.40.40\Administrator %password%
```

2. Use a special character escape sequence. Use a double percent symbol:

```
    net use \\192.168.40.40  /user:192.168.40.40\Administrator b91A*9AIvPr%%
```

3. Escape the quotations with `^`:

```
    net use \\192.168.40.40  /user:192.168.40.40\Administrator ^"b91A*9AIvPr%^"
```

Comment: I can't test it now because I don't have a Windows machine at hand , but I've got a feeling that your 2nd solution %% will literally insert 2 % signs in the password.  Escaping the " in the 3rd one may actually pass through the " as part of the password. Escaping the % by using a ^ aka: ˆ% is another option and to me is more logical than either your 2nd and 3rd suggestion.

Comment: %% version works :В